# Which argument changed in Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

Is it possible to find out which variable changed in manipulate?

I've got a solution here, but it's kludgy, and I wonder if there is any way to get this information directly from the system?

(If you have any trouble understanding the question, just run this code, which works correctly.)

```
Module[{oldParams}, 
   ControlChanged[parameters_List] := 
      ControlActive[
         Position[MapThread[UnsameQ, {oldParams, parameters}], True][[1, 1]], 
         oldParams = parameters; 
         None
       ]
]; 

Manipulate[
   ControlChanged[{x, y, z}], 
   {x, 0, 1}, 
   {y, 0, 1},
   {z, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: It may matter what do you want and what do you want to use it for. Is the index all you need?

Comment: Sure. I want to recalculate based on what changed. I have a large set of variables which have relations, e.g. x + y == 1. If the user changes x, I want to recalculate y and leave x alone. If the user changes y, I want to recalculate x and leave y alone.

Comment: `If the user changes x, I want to recalculate y and leave x alone. If the user changes y, I want to recalculate x and leave y alone`  be careful with this. You'll end up in an infinite loop. If you modify a control variable inside Manipulate expression, it will automatically trigger another update and you will easily go to infinite loop, having to terminate the kernel from task bar. The basic rule of thumb is Manipulate, is to treat control variables as read-only. There are ways to work around this, but this will require different design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a function `track[var]` that will set a "tracking" variable `var` to the held variable which changes.  Just use it as the setting for `TrackingFunction`, wrapped with `Evaluate[]`. Why is `Evaluate` needed? Good question. It works with it and it doesn't work without it. `Manipulate` holds its arguments, but evaluates some of them at certain points during the construction of the output. In particular, it tests the option value for `TrackingFunction`. (It will revert to the default function, if the value is not a valid `Function` or `List` of functions.)  Evidently, `Evaluate` is important somewhere along the line.

```
ClearAll[track];
SetAttributes[track, HoldAll];
track[var_] := {Function[{val, u}, var = Hold[u], HoldRest], 
   Function[{val, u}, u = val, HoldRest], # &};
Manipulate[Column@{
   {var, Hold[x], var === Hold[x]},
   Grid[{{x, y, z}}, Frame -> All, 
     Background -> {{Hold[x], Hold[y], Hold[z]} /. {var -> Red, _Hold -> None}, None}]
   },
 {x, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> Evaluate@track[var]},
 {y, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> Evaluate@track[var]},
 {z, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> Evaluate@track[var]},
 {{var, None}, None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "TrackingFunction" is the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: This duplicates the code I wrote above:

Comment: Module[{cc},
 cc = None;
 Manipulate[
  cc,
  {x, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> ((cc = 1; x = #) &)},
  {y, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> ((cc = 2; y = #) &)},
  {z, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> ((cc = 3; z = #) &)}
  ]
 ]

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you right, One way to do this, is to use the second argument of dynamics. Each dynamic control can use this as a place to record that it was selected, and update a common variable.

Then when Manipulate updates, simply examine this variable to see which control caused the Manipulate to update.

In this example, this common variable `controlVariableName` is just string of the name of the control, but you can make it anything else you want. Also the common variable `controlVariableItself` will contain the control variable value itself. i.e. `x` or `y`, etc...

```
Manipulate[

 Grid[{
   {Style[Row[{"changed [", controlVariableName, "] control!"}], Red],
     SpanFromLeft},
   {Style[Row[{"Its current value [", controlVariableItself , "]"}], 
     Red], SpanFromLeft},
   {"x=", x, "y=", y, "z=", z}
   }],

 (*controls*)
 Grid[{{"x", 
    Manipulator[
     Dynamic[x, {x = #, controlVariableName = "x", 
        controlVariableItself = x} &], {0, 1, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny],
     Dynamic[x]}, {"y", 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[y, {y = #, controlVariableName = "y", 
        controlVariableItself = y} &], {0, 1, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny],
     Dynamic[y]}, {"z", 
    Manipulator[Dynamic[z, {z = #, controlVariableName = "z", 
        controlVariableItself = z} &], {0, 1, .1}, ImageSize -> Tiny],
     Dynamic[z]},
   {Button[
     Text@Style["press me", 12], { controlVariableName = "Button", 
      controlVariableItself = "Button"}]}
   }],

 {{controlVariableName, "x"}, None},
 {{controlVariableItself, x}, None},
 {{x, 0}, None},
 {{y, 0}, None},
 {{z, 0}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {x, y, z}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is more like it, but can I get to that second argument from Manipulate? Or do I have to break it all out that way?

Comment: @CharlesGillingham If you mean pass the variable value itself, instead of just its name as string as in the example? Sure. I've updated the answer.

Comment: These are interesting applications of the answer to this question.

Comment: What I personally want to do is enforce constraints between a set of parameters. E.g. If  x+y == 1, then I want `{x,0,1,TrackingFunction->((x = #; y = 1 - x;&)}`